# TreeModelAdapter with Search Functionality

Tags: java, tapestry

I'm currently working with Tapestry 5.3 now, and using a Tree Component to display hierarchy of account list which has 4 levels. But now I'm struggling with search functionality in this scenario:

```
Level 1-1
|_ _ _ Level 2-1 
|_ _ _ Level 2-2
       |_ _ _ Level 3-1
       |_ _ _ Level 3-2
       |      |_ _ _ Level 4-1
       |      |_ _ _ Level 4-2
       |_ _ _ Level 3-3
```

For example. User wants to searched account Level 4-1, the tree should displayed like this

```
Level 1-1
|_ _ _ Level 2-2
       |_ _ _ Level 3-2
              |_ _ _ Level 4-1
```

Can someone please help me this logic stuff? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've figured it out.

I created a new class `AccountTreeModelAdapter` which is implements [TreeModelAdapter](https://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/tree/TreeModelAdapter.html). You can override the `getChildren` method and put your search logic there. For me it works in this flow:

- Add `setSearchedAccounts(List<Account> searchedAccounts)` method in `AccountTreeModelAdapter`
- Set it's value from your main class
- In `getChildren` method, use `Iterator` to iterate your whole list (all accounts) and compare one by one with each Account's code in `searchedAccounts` list (using `searchedAccounts.stream().filter()` in Java 8).

Voila, now the tree will only display accounts you desire.
But, how to display the parent? Until this point, the tree not showing the parent and the parent's parent and the parent's parent again and again until you reach the ROOT.

To accomplish this, I create a new column for my Account entity in database. Which is `accountPath`. So every time user create an account, this `accountPath` will work like this:

```
Account "ABC" (ID: 1)
    |_ _ _ "XYZ" (ID: 2)
        |_ _ _ "OPQ" (ID: 3)
            |_ _ _ "STU" (ID: 4)
```

Account "ABC" will has no path (since it's a ROOT).
Account "XYZ" will has path -1-
Account "OPQ" will has path -1-2-
Account "STU" will has path -1-2-3-

To get each parent's ID, use string.split("-")

So, if you want the tree to display the parent, you can simply just add the parent account to `searchedAccounts` list.

That's all.